# Single Product Page with Weight and Dimensions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I know it is possible to show product's weight and dimensions in a specific tab, but I would want it at another place : just before the SKU and categories.

Is there a plugin, a hook or a code to add in functions.php, that I can use in order to do that ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Create a function that will output the weight and dimensions if they are defined, and then hook to `woocommerce_single_product_summary` with something like: `add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_additional_info', 40);`, where `show_additional_info` is your function.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that both weight and dimensions are defined and I found that [link](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/display-product-dimensions-on-archive-pages/).
Nevertheless, I don't know PHP and don't understand how to create a function. Can you help me on that ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `functions.php` add something like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'cj_show_dimensions', 40 );
function cj_show_dimensions() {
    global $product;
    $dimensions = $product->get_dimensions();
        if ( ! empty( $dimensions ) ) {
                echo '<span class="dimensions">' . $dimensions . '</span>';
        }
}
```

This should output the dimensions where you need it if the product has defined dimensions.